# static_cast taking away constness

Tags: c++, static-cast, const-cast

From my knowledge (and this topic: [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)) `const_cast` is the only cast that should be able to take away constness of a variable. However, when messing around with `clang-6.0` and `g++5.4.0` I stumbled upon a behaviour that would contradict the above. It seems `static_cast` does exactly the same job.

These main functions give the exact same results with both compilers:

test class definition

```
struct Base {
        Base() {
                std::cout << "Base::Base()\n";
        }
        void test() const {
                std::cout << "Base::test()\n";
        }

        void no_const() {
                std::cout << "Base::no_const()\n";
        }

        virtual ~Base() = default;
};
```

with `const_cast`

```
int main(void) {
        std::cout << "BEGIN\n";
        const Base b;
        const_cast<Base&>(b).no_const();

        std::cout << "END\n";
}
```

with `static_cast`

```
int main(void) {
        std::cout << "BEGIN\n";
        const Base b;
        static_cast<Base>(b).no_const();

        std::cout << "END\n";
}
```

Result:

```
BEGIN
Base::Base()
Base::no_const()
END
```

What gives?

Comment: You are playing a sleight of hand. The two casts are dissimilar - one casts to `Base&` reference, the other to `Base` - this involves creating a temporary copy; it does not cast away constness from the original. If you try `static_cast<Base&>(b)`, you'll get the error you've expected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a copy constructor definition for `Base`, it'll answer your question.

```
Base(Base const&) {
        std::cout << "Base::Base(Base const&)\n";
}
```

The output from your second example changes to

```
BEGIN
Base::Base()
Base::Base(Base const&)
Base::no_const()
END
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43d544793473f425)

---

Attempt to cast away constness from `b` itself, and you'll see an error

```
static_cast<Base&>(b).no_const();
//              ^
```

> error: invalid `static_cast` from type '`const Base`' to type '`Base&`'
>
> ```
>   static_cast<Base&>(b).no_const();
> ```

Comment: Ah, the copy constructor - that's the building block I forgot. Shame on me! Thanks a lot!